# WordPress Thesis + Livefyre Not in Framework

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme, livefyre

I am running WordPress' Thesis. I have installed the LiveFyre plugin. If you see my site, the comments form is not within the framework. I have tried CSS and div classes but can't seem to get the LiveFyre form to show up underneath the blog content.

Does anyone have any suggestions here? There is no widget for LiveFyre, which makes it even more interesting.

Having issues on my post pages: http://exigodigital.com/2013/12/tips-building-digital-ad-budget/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own issue.

So easy I can't believe I overlooked it.

You have to disable WordPress' commenting platform before it will enable another commenting platform.